# How is dodge chance calculated in Diablo 3 Reaper of Souls?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know the dodge chance calculation had been modified in RoS.

I've seen many Demon Hunters with 8000+ dexterity. The old formula will get >100% dodge chance which doesn't make sense.
eg. A demon hunter has a dexterity of 8943.
The battle.net profile page as of today (4/16/2014) still seems to use the old formula and shows this 109.43% dodge chance.

[image]

In game, it shows a correct dodge chance, but what's the new formula then?

BTW, the old formula in Diablo 3 is

```
if (Dexterity <= 100)
  DodgeChance = Dexterity * 0.001;
else if (Dexterity <= 500)
  DodgeChance = (Dexterity - 100) * 0.00025 + 0.1;
else if (Dexterity <= 1000)
  DodgeChance = (Dexterity - 500) * 0.0002 + 0.2;
else if (Dexterity <= 8000)
  DodgeChance = (Dexterity - 1000) * 0.0001 + 0.3;
else
  DodgeChance = 1;
```

plus some skill dodge chance bonus.

Comment: @StrixVaria Not a duplicate.  He mentions the old formula - which has since changed.  This looks like a good question since that one you linked hasn't been touched in 2 years.

Comment: @Mkalafut It pained me to vote to close as dupe, but our policy is that even if the answers change, the question is still a dupe. I unaccepted the old answer (since it's now incorrect). Hopefully someone will put the updated answer on that question.

Comment: @StrixVaria Fair enough.  Though I thought I recall a discussion in meta regarding outdated *expansion* content being suitable for new questions (like Reaper of Souls & FTL:AE).  Either way if it's closed so be it.  I was just putting in my 2 cents. =)

Comment: @StrixVaria Diablo 3 RoS could be considered as an expansion or even a different game from the original Diablo 3. I saw the old post, that's why I put RoS in the title. The answer to that old post is still correct.

Comment: No, the answer to the old post is wrong, because it was changed retroactively and even affects people playing vanilla.

Comment: Minor point about the question: the image says "*increases* dodge chance by 109%" This is a lot different than "100% dodge chance"